# JTextPane : How do you update it after adding it to a layout?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I've posted a question similar to this before, but anyway, I guess this explains my problem better. Please refer to this [link](http://jexp.ru/index.php/Java_by_API/javax.swing/JTextPane#JTextPane%3a_replaceSelection.28String_content.29). If you notice, all examples suggest that your textpane content has to prepared before it is added to the content pane! Why is this so?

For instance, this piece of code:

```
    public class PaneInsertionMethods {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
    pane.replaceSelection("text");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(360, 180);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

works well. But, if I try to do something like this:

```
public class PaneTest extends JFrame {
private JTextPane pane;
public PaneTest() {
   initComponents();
}
private void initComponents() {
    pane = new JTextPane();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(360, 180);
    setVisible(true);
}
public void populatePane() {
    pane.replaceSelection("text");  
   //or something like this.. doesn't work
   //pane.revalidate(); pane.repaint();

}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    PaneTest test = new PaneTest();
    test.populatePane();
    //or even something like this doesn't work:
    //SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    // public void run() {
    //     test.populatePane();
    //   }});
}}
```

All I get to see is a empty textpane in the second example. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well first of all, there is not really ever a good reason to subclass JFrame. replaceSelection is meant to replace text selected by the user. Are you sure you are not looking for the setText (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) method?

Comment: in my actual code a JDialog is being subclassed. The idea is to update caret position to existing text position - something like this: textpane.setCaretPosition(textPane.getDocument().getLength()) and then call textpane.replaceSelection() which actually does an insert.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured that replaceSelection doesn't insert text when the textpane is not editable (in my case it was not editable!) - I can't believe I read the javadoc on this like 50 times, but I kept missing that one line. Anyway, problem solved now!

Comment: ok.. it works when I do this: test.populatePane(); test.setVisible(true); and not when test.setVisible(true);test.populatePane(); I even tried calling test.populatePane() from SwingUtilities.InvokeLater() - doesn't work.

Comment: looks like I have to always populate pane first and then display - why is this so?

Comment: found my answer again - the JDialog cannot be modal - if it is modal, you cannot modify a textpane inside it after you make the dialog visible!!

Comment: yes you can, but your code isn't called before the dialog is closed.